# Capybara + Selenium: How to select second item in Chosen.js multiselect list?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, selenium, capybara, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to use Capybara + Selenium to select the first item after the initial blank in a Chosen.js multiselect list.

I've got two halves, but I'm struggling to put them together. That is to say, I've successfully used the following snippet to [select an item from a select box based on its index](http://jasonneylon.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/selecting-from-a-dropdown-generically-with-capybara/):

```
def select_second_option(id)
  second_option_xpath = "//*[@id='#{id}']/option[2]"
  second_option = find(:xpath, second_option_xpath).text
  select(second_option, :from => id)
end
```

...and the following is [said to work](https://gist.github.com/thijsc/1391107#comment-319702) for selecting a chosen field:

```
def select_from_chosen(item_text, options)
  field = find_field(options[:from], visible: false)
  option_value = page.evaluate_script("$(\"##{field[:id]} option:contains('#{item_text}')\").val()")
  page.execute_script("value = ['#{option_value}']\; if ($('##{field[:id]}').val()) {$.merge(value, $('##{field[:id]}').val())}")
  option_value = page.evaluate_script("value")
  page.execute_script("$('##{field[:id]}').val(#{option_value})")
  page.execute_script("$('##{field[:id]}').trigger('liszt:updated').trigger('change')")
end
```

But I can't seem to get the two concepts to play nice.

How can I combine these ideas such that I have a function of the form `select_second_option_from_chosen(id)`?

Answer (score 4):

in your support folder create module

```
module Utilities
  def select_from_chosen(item_text, options)
    field = find_field(options[:from])
    option_value = page.evaluate_script("$(\"##{field[:id]} option:contains('#{item_text}')\").val()")
    page.execute_script("$('##{field[:id]}').val('#{option_value}')")
    page.execute_script("$('##{field[:id]}').trigger('liszt:updated').trigger('change')")
  end
end
```

in your **spec_helper** add

```
config.include(Utilities)
```

and then you can call the function in your **capybara test**

```
select_from_chosen("User", :from => "user_role_ids")
```

**HTML**

```
<%= f.collection_select :role_ids, [[:admin, 'Admin'],[:sonar, 'User']], :first, :last, {}, { :class => 'chzn-select' } %>
```